# Sync between Sql Server and Mysql Server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, synchronization

I have 2 big tables in sql server that i need to sync to mysql.
now, i need that as an ongoing process.
the tables are 1 GB each and getting new/update/delete row every 0.1 second.

Can you recommend me a tool that can do it that is not resource expensive.

you can offer OPEN SOURCE and commercial as well

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You could create a linked server instance in SQL Server, pointing to the MySQL instance.  [This article gives the step-by-step process](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/).  Once that is in place, providing you grant the MySQL user you connect on behalf of proper permissions, you can write to the MySQL instance as you like.  So you could easily update stored procedures to do an additional step to insert records into MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've been looking for a very long time for how to solve our problem of running our asset management system on MS SQL while running our CMS on MySQL. Your answer helped solve our problem of not being able to connect to each other. THANK YOU!

Comment: Link rot! Could you add a short self-contained guide within the answer?