# SQL Server sync to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sync between Sql Server and Mysql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951174/sync-between-sql-server-and-mysql-server)

I want to continually sync every 30 mins or less around 380000 rows of data from 11 table from a SQL Server database to a MySQL database. How can I do this? What programs can do this?

Both servers are remote.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951174/sync-between-sql-server-and-mysql-server

Comment: Yep, as described in the linked question. It's then just a matter of creating a SQL Agent job to run when you need it to to sync the data you need copied.

Comment: Okay, sorry for creating a duplicate question! Thanks