# SQL Server sync to MySQL program

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

I want to continually sync every 30 mins or less around 380000 rows of data from 11 tables from a SQL Server database to a MySQL database. How can I do this? What programs can do this?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951174/sync-between-sql-server-and-mysql-server), which is often used to close questions like these as a duplicate, does not work for me, for the following reasons.

The SQL Server is part of a CRM system, I'm not sure if it may be a lite version or something, but long story short I *do not have access to the SQL Server Management Studio.*

The MySQL database is part of my hosting package, which means I have access to it via `phpmyadmin` and the like, but not to the console or anything. And obviously I cannot access it via `localhost`.

So basically what I'm looking for is a way to connect to both databases, probably via ODBC drivers, and sync data every x minutes/hours.

Comment: Duplicate of the previous duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259953/mssql-sync-to-mysql

Comment: It wasn't a duplicate in the end...... and it was closed and I don't know how to open it again.

Comment: It would help if you can be more specific about why other answers don't work for you: there are already [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sync+mysql+sql+server) about syncing data between SQL Server and MySQL. And it isn't clear what you by both servers being "remote" and why you think that affects the solution.

Comment: @Pondlife: just the fact that there are many questions does not mean there are also answers. A quick browse through first page of your link reveals only erroneous solutions (linked server based, never viable in real deployments).

Comment: @RemusRusanu Agreed, but the question as stated is indistinguishable from the many other questions on this topic and shows little evidence of research. Browsing previous questions - whether or not they have good answers - is an excellent way to clarify your own requirements and thoughts, and may lead to new avenues of research or suggest entirely new ways of looking at a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used a program called Omega Sync. *Now called [Spectral Core Replicator](https://www.spectralcore.com/replicator)*.

> Omega Sync can compare and synchronize both database schema and table data. Schema comparison and synchronization for databases of same kind
>   Data comparison and synchronization even for databases of different kind
>   Compare and Synchronize databases of unlimited size!

Supported databases

- Access
- SQL Server
- MySQL
- Oracle
- Interbase
- Firebird
- ODBC sources

*I am not associated with this company or product in any way.*

Comment: To anybody thinking this is spam - I saw that this question is getting a lot of views - so thought that it should be properly composed

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server replication can apply the changes to generic ODBC/OleDB subscribers. You can configure MySQL as a subscriber if you follow the right steps and use the correct drivers, but is not officially supported so you are on your own if something goes wrong. Eg. see [Set up replication between Microsoft SQL Server 2000 and MySQL](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-set-up-replication-between-microsoft-sql-server-2000-and-mysql/112). since the article is for SQL 2000 is already [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143550%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) since Microsoft SQL 2008 supports [OleDB subscribers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151864%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), not ODBC.

You will need a very deep understanding of both Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, ODBC/OleDB and Microsoft SQL Server replication. If you hit errors you'll have to solve them on your own, as the public information on this subject is scarce. I can only tell you that is possible and I've seen it done. Good Luck!

Comment: I don't have access to the SQL Server Manager, as it is part of a program.