# Overnight sync from MsSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

I am in need to run a nightly sync from a MSSQL server containing around 200 tables to a MySQL server. I have readonly access to MSSQL server and full access to the MySQL server.

Ideally I would like an automated solution where the database on MSSQL syncs with the MySQL server but I am willing to use a  solution where I have to manually go in a trigger it.

Right now I would have to delete the entire database on MySQL and rerun the migration job on MySQL workbench to migrate from MSSQL. The MySQL server is on a REHL7 box to which I have access sudo access to.

Comment: Do you have access/knowledge of an app tool like Java or C#?  It would be relatively straightforward to write a daily job which does the migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server sync to MySQL program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263998/sql-server-sync-to-mysql-program)